# Mac Mini mouse icon stutters and sometimes unresponsive

Tags: macos, performance, mac-mini, magic-trackpad

The mouse icon on my Mac Mini (macmini6,2 - 10.14.1) has started stuttering. It's not always, but most often. Sometimes it's so bad the icon won't move at all and I cannot click with my Magic Trackpad 2.

I've looked at Activity Monitor (and `top`) but it doesn't show that it is doing much at all. I've closed down the more intensive background apps (e.g. Plex) but it doesn't seem to help.

A restart seems to improve things initially, but then it comes back.

I also occasionally see a grey box with a spinning sun like icon in it appear every so often. No idea what that is!

Looking for some guidance to locate the offending process, or if it is hardware etc.

I'm going to update macOS and see how that goes!

Comment: You've thoroughly cleaned the hole the diode sits in, and blown any stray cat hair out of there? Have you tried using a different, slightly rougher surface to mouse on. Once every couple years I have to scuff up the finish, polyurethane, on my oak library table to give the mouse something it can see moving. 400 grit is good enough. You won't notice it, but your mouse will.

Comment: It's a trackpad not a mouse.

Comment: Ah, title reads mouse. Get someone to change it for you. My trackpad sits in my drawer, all but unused.

Comment: Do you see the same stuttering behavior when you plug the Magic TrackPad in to your Mini with its charging cable?

Comment: @KarlC It has only been a few hours, and I'd want to test this over days, connecting the MagicTrackpad 2 via a lightning cable directly to the Mac Mini does seem to have improved my issues. Any idea what would cause what I therefore assume is a bluetooth issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine two possibilities.

1. Someone cleaned the trackpad with a detergent that created a charge on the surface of the trackpad, which is disrupting the capacitive touch mechanism.
2. If the trackpad is connected via Bluetooth, you have a microwave source near you that is disrupting the signal e.g. a leaky microwave oven in a break room.